# What does card_id => () => submitData(param_name, param_addr) do

Tags: node.js

Iam going through one of nodejs app and can find a syntax where code is:

```
const deleteData = async (
  param_name,
  param_addr
) => {
    await callRequests(post_no, card_id => () => submitData(param_name, param_addr)
    );
}
```

Iam not pretty sure what the double '=>' means here- " => () => " in the last line. Is it kind of double arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

It's an lambda (arrow function) that returns a lambda.

A concrete example:

```
const sortFactory = (sign) => (a, b) => (a - b) * sign
const arr = [1, 3, 4, 2]
arr.sort(sortFactory(1)) // ascending
arr.sort(sortFactory(-1)) // ascending
```

In this question, it's a lambda with argument `card_id` that returns a no-argument lambda `() => submitData(param_name, param_addr)`

Comment: what does leading "card_id => " do in arrow function. I mean there is double "=>" and paranthesis in between